# HTML5 LocalStorage not persistent on blackberry after Power Off

Tags: html, blackberry, cordova

I have been working on an app for Android, IOS and Blackberry using PhoneGap this application is using localStorage to keep a auth_key between accesses.  My Issue is that when I reboot hard reset (battery Pull) the Blackberry all localStorage variables are lost.

Same application in Android and iOS is working just fine, data is maintained between reboots of the hardware both soft and hard resets (battery pull Android).

Is there something special that needs to be done for Blackberry to maintain this data through a battery pull?

Just incase.. here is the code i am using to set and get the variables

```
localStorage.setItem('key', '(some radomstring)');

var key = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that on some blackberry devices in order to retain data through a battery pull you must have SD card installed in the phone.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Blackberry OS are you working on ? I have tested this on my Blackberry bold 9900 which is running on OS7. Localstorage is perfectly persistent. Below is the code i used.

localStorage['auth_key'] = "xyz_key";

alert(localStorage['auth_key']);

after powercycle it alerts "xyz_key" perfectly.

I even don't have SD card installed on my phone.